# Javascript 19 digits number changing the last digits to zeroes

Tags: javascript

I ran into this issue when trying to get the last 4 digits of a 19 digits numeric value.

```js
let payload={
card: 1234567891238475891
}
let stringCardNumber = '' + payload.card;
console.log(payload.card)
console.log(stringCardNumber)
console.log( stringCardNumber.slice(stringCardNumber.length - 4))
let zeroedCardNumber = stringCardNumber.slice(0, 6) + "".padStart(stringCardNumber.length - 10, "0") + stringCardNumber.slice(stringCardNumber.length - 4);
console.log(zeroedCardNumber)
```

So for `1234567891238475891`, the output log is `1234567891238475800`.

Changing the card value to string in the json itself is not the solution I am expecting, since there will be cases where 19 digits number is expected.

Comment: JavaScript numbers cannot hold integers that large. The "Big Int" type can but it's not supported in all browsers. You're converting the number to a string anyway, so make it start out as a string.

Comment: The "json" wouldn't have that value unless it was a string. So your hardcoded value should be a string not a number. https://playcode.io/697817/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number is too large for JavaScript's default [numerical representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) so you need to use the longer form with [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
card: 1234567891238475891n
```

A better approach is to just use a string as these aren't really "numbers" in the conventional sense and as Pointy adds, support for BigInt is a relatively new thing so if support for older browsers is important it won't be a solution.

JSON does not enforce BigInt support, so numerical values this large may well get rounded. Using a string is the most reliable way to ensure this data flows through correctly.

Comment: Also BigInt has imperfect support across browsers.

Comment: @Pointy Internet Explorer is effectively dead, and it was the hold-out here, so it may not be an issue, but yeah, strings are better.

Comment: Well my company is inherently US-only and we get a surprising number of IE11 visitors. *edit* maybe "depressing" is a better word

Comment: @Pointy Your country still has dollar bills, pennies, and magnetic swipe cards, so yeah, feel for you there.

Comment: The problem was actually the input value from the angular formgroup was getting this issue and to replicate it, had to use the json. Thanks for the answer.